# How to use v-model using props in v-for in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, v-for, v-model, vue-props

I want to use v-model using props in v-for. I used v-model with props before using computed variables, but don't know how to do in v-for.

This is my code:

```html
<script setup>
const fieldValue = computed({
  get() {
    return props.modelValue;
  },
  set(value) {
    emits('update:modelValue', value);
  },
});
</script>
<template>
  <Mentionable
    v-for="(field, index) in props.data.placeholder"
    :key="index"
    :keys="['#']"
    :items="props.data.items"
  >
    <textarea
      v-model="fieldValue"
      :disabled="!props.data.loaded"
      :placeholder="field.placeholder"
      :maxlength="props.maxLength"
      :required="props.required"
    />
  </Mentionable>
</template>
```

Note: `Mentionable` is the component from `vue-mention` library.

Answer (score 0):

Use `model-value` and `update:model-value` event instend of `v-model`.

If the component does not provide `model-value` and `update:model-value` event, there must be prop and event you can do the same.

A example, `AInput` from [Ant Design Vue](https://github.com/vueComponent/ant-design-vue) provides value prop and change event.

```html
<script setup name="Demo">
  const {ref} from 'vue'
  const arrayInputs = ref(['1', 'test', '3'])
  function change(i, event) {
    arrayInputs.value[i] = event.target.value
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div class="vue-component">
    <h2>ant-design-vue</h2>
    <template v-for="(item, index) in arrayInputs" :key="index">
      <!-- the index is important -->
      <AInput :value="item" @change="event => change(index, event)" />
    </template>
    <div>{{ arrayInputs }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```